# Get sequences of occurrences in large string of html-text

Tags: javascript, regex, fetch

I am using *fetch* to get an HTML file. So far I've only figured out how to get the response back as an array of text, using the text() method:

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    longAssText = text;
    textExtract = longAssText.match(/<table class='listing' id='customer-tickets'>[\s\S]*<script type='text\/javascript'>/gi);
});
```

The string I get back looks something like this (textExtract):

```
<span class="status status_active">active</span></td>
<td><a href="/tickets/365347-SOME-TITLE">#365347 SOME-TITLE</a></td>
<td>2018-03-12 09:14:34</td>
<td>2018-03-12 10:12:46</td>
<td>some category</td>
</tr>
<tr class='even'>
<td>
<img align="absmiddle" alt="Service_request_ticket" src="/images/service_request_ticket.gif?1520519528" title="some attribute" />
<img align="absmiddle" alt="Number_1" src="/images/number_1.gif?1520519528" title="Saken ligger hos 1. linje" />
<img align="absmiddle" alt="Flag_disabled" src="/images/flag_disabled.png?1520519528" title="Priority: Normal" />
</td>
<td class='ttstatus'><span class="status status_closed">closed</span></td>
<td><a href="/tickets/150640-vs-sender-e-post-brn001ba9bd7a93_000186">#150640 VS: SOME TITLE</a></td>
<td>2013-11-06 08:12:35</td>
<td>2013-11-20 21:00:11</td>
<td>Some category</td>
</tr>
<tr class='odd'>
<td>
```

I want to extract the text inside every a-tag prepended with the *status_active* class: "#365347 SOME-TITLE".

So in:

```
<a href="/tickets/365347-SOME-TITLE">#365347 SOME-TITLE</a>
```

I want to extract *#365347 SOME-TITLE*.

..every a-tag after a span.status_active.

I'm having a hard time with regex. I was thinking of getting all instances with regex, but I cant even get the first match.

I've tried patterns like this 
`from([\s\S]*?)to`
but I'm really having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

The closest I've managed is:

```
(status_active)[^._]*(?=\.)
```

But not every text has a . at the end..

Is regex the way to go? If so could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand, you want the text inside every a tag after a specific span, or only the first one?

Comment: Text inside every a-tag after a span.status_active. I've updated the question to reflect this in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is **not** the way to go.

Please use an html parser (for example [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)):

```
parser = new DOMParser();
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
...
```

See also this *famous* SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/709439)... :-)

Comment: I do not know why someone would down vote this. It is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var regex = /status_active.*?\n*.*<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gm
var matches = text.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Another approach could be to use jQuery to parse the text and to use selectors to find the corresponding nodes. Like MarcoS already stated: This would be a much cleaner solution, since regexes are not the best tool for parsing xml structures.